# password protect a single page, and do not show any admin menus to the user

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, password-protection

I've tried the "Protected Node" module, but that goes to the 404 instead of the password prompt page which it's supposed to give.

Also tried the "Simple Access" module, and after getting it to control access, realised that it still shows users the "edit" menu and there doesn't seem to be a way to switch it off for them.

Thanks to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 2):

I have used the "Node Access" module before. But for one site I had to work on recently, I needed something that allows me to restrict access for anonymous users on a single page. Only visitors, who have received the password should have access.
Installing the Node Access module and creating a specific role seemed to be an overkill for this limited requirement, and I went with the "[Protected Pages](https://drupal.org/project/protected_pages)" module, which allows to set a password for a certain path. (d7 only)

Answer (score 0):

Access to the admin is usually controlled via the user permissions as for limiting access to a specific page, this could be achieved with [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels).

Answer (score 0):

Use [NodeAccess](http://drupal.org/project/nodeaccess) module to restrict that page based on role.

> Users with the 'grant node permissions' permission will have a grant
>   tab on node pages which allows them to grant access to that node by
>   user or role.